# no ssjavacom.dll in JAVA LIBRrary path

Tags: path, 32bit-64bit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqWE8.png)

I added `SSJavaCOM.dll` in `windows/System32` folder. I added the path. Still it remains. How to tackle this ? 
I copied `SSjavaCOM.dll` from `enterprise architect-8: 32 bit` to `System32` folder for conversion of uml file to XML schema file using shapechange java api.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to put some *more effort* into formatting your question with more proper english (with, , . ? upper and lower case), and format code and path between ` or this will be deleted very quickly. You might want also to ask a more clear question, more details are needed here.

Comment: Pardon my language. Error got rectified. Thank you

Comment: I did the corrections for english and code formatting. Can you put instead of an image, the code/ouput and format it ?

Comment: java -jar ShapeChange-2.5.1.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 "File Path\file name".  The issue was with my system. Java-32bit is required for this code. Even Though after adding java-32 bit, API takes the path of Java (in Program Files folder). Later ti got rectified. Now everything is running fine. Sorry for the trouble. Thank you for your response.